# Why is my jquery only working sequentially?

Tags: jquery

Working in a project using JQuery 1.11. I have multiple rows of data, each having two select boxes. The second one in each row should be disabled until the first one is set to a specific value.

The code that I have works... but weirdly, it only works if you do them in sequential order. If I go to anything except the first one first, it doesn't update.

Could someone please clue me in on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/JCOvergaar/xLdp6wgo/9/

And for posterity, here's the code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.ThisFirstThings', function() {

  var dataFlag = $(".ThisFirstThings option:selected").attr('data-flag');
  if (dataFlag == 1) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".SecondThing").prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".SecondThing").prop('disabled', true)
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```
  <form name="ThisForm" id="ThisForm">
    <div id="divDVT">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select name="ThisFirstThing_1" id="ThisFirstThing_1" class="ThisFirstThings">
                <option value="106" data-flag="0">No change</option>
                <option value="107" data-flag="0">No change</option>
                <option value="205" data-flag="1">Should Enable -></option>
              </select> </td>
            <td>
              <select name="ThisSecondThing_1" id="ThisSecondThing_1" class="SecondThing" disabled="">
                <option value="43">one thing</option>
                <option value="82">another</option>
              </select> </td>
            <td>
              <input type="Submit" name="ThisSubmit" value="Submit"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select name="ThisFirstThing_2" id="ThisFirstThing_2" class="ThisFirstThings">
                <option value="106" data-flag="0">No change</option>
                <option value="107" data-flag="0">No change</option>
                <option value="205" data-flag="1">Should Enable -></option>
              </select> </td>
            <td>
              <select name="ThisSecondThing_2" id="ThisSecondThing_2" class="SecondThing" disabled="">
                <option value="43">one thing</option>
                <option value="82">another</option>
              </select> </td>
            <td>
              <input type="Submit" name="ThisSubmit" value="Submit"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: use `$(this).find("option:selected")` instead of  
 `var dataFlag = $(".ThisFirstThings option:selected").attr('data-flag');`  https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/up7yhmvj/

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change

`var dataFlag = $(".ThisFirstThings option:selected").attr('data-flag');`

to

`var dataFlag = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-flag');`

Original `dataFlag` was getting all `select.ThisFirstThings` in the page.
Change targets only changed `select.ThisFirstThings`

Comment: Thanks, Ethan -- That resolved the issue. And I appreciate learning *why* it wasn't working, too. Makes it more likely I won't make the mistake again in another environment.